# MS SQL Создать функцию, формирующую направления для студентов, не сдавших экзамены, к случайным преподавателям, ведущим эти дисциплины

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос

Всех приветствую, стоит передо мной вот такая задачка: "Создать функцию, формирующую направления для студентов, не сдавших экзамены, к случайным преподавателям, ведущим эти дисциплины", имеются следующие таблицы:

Группы (Номер_Группы, Староста_Группы)

Студенты (Код_Студента, Фамилия, Имя, Отчество, Номер_Зачетной_Книжки, Номер_Группы, Домашний_Адрес, Телефон)

Дисциплины (Код_Дисциплины, Название, Количество_Часов, Описание)

Результаты_Сессии (Код_Студента, Код_Дисциплины, Дата, Вид_Контроля, Оценка)

Преподаватели (Код_Преподавателя, Фамилия, Имя, Отчество, Должность, Ученая_Степень, Дата_Приема_На_Работу, Номер_Кафедры)

Нагрузка (Код_Дисциплины, Код_Преподавателя)

Скриншот диаграммы:
[image: Диаграмма]

Условия решение задачи:
Нельзя использовать оконные функции, нельзя использовать CTE, задачка должна решаться элементарно, без слишком усложненных конструкций.
Для рандома используется представление:
`CREATE VIEW dbo.Рандом AS SELECT NEWID() AS Рандомное_Значение; GO`
(Поскольку при создании функции нельзя использовать ORDER BY NEWID(), это что-то типо обхода)

Решения которые были забракованы:

1. `SELECT`
   `s.Код_Студента,`
   `s.Фамилия,`
   `s.Имя,`
   `s.Отчество,`
   `s.Номер_Группы,`
   `r.Код_Дисциплины,`
   `p.Код_Преподавателя,`
   `p.Фамилия AS Преподаватель_Фамилия,`
   `p.Имя AS Преподаватель_Имя`
   `FROM`
   `Студенты s`
   `JOIN Результаты_Сессии r ON s.Код_Студента = r.Код_Студента`
   `JOIN Нагрузка n ON r.Код_Дисциплины = n.Код_Дисциплины`
   `JOIN Преподаватели p ON n.Код_Преподавателя = p.Код_Преподавателя`
   `CROSS JOIN Рандом as rnd`
   `WHERE`
   `r.Вид_Контроля = 'Экзамен'`
   `AND r.Оценка < 3`
   `ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.Код_Студента ORDER BY rnd.Рандомное_значение)`

Причина браковки: Используется оконная функция

2. `SELECT  T1.*,` 
       `(`
          `SELECT Код_Преподавателя FROM`
          `(`
           `SELECT TOP 1 T2.Код_Преподавателя, (SELECT Рандомное_Значение FROM Рандом) as rnd`
           `FROM Нагрузка AS T2`
           `JOIN Результаты_Сессии AS T3 ON T2.Код_Дисциплины = T3.Код_Дисциплины`
           `WHERE T3.Код_Студента = T1.Код_Студента AND T2.Код_Дисциплины = T1.Код_Дисциплины`
           `ORDER BY rnd`
           `) AS Случайный_преподователь`
       `) AS Код_Преподавателя`
   `FROM` 
      `Результаты_Сессии AS T1`
   `WHERE T1.Вид_Контроля = 'Экзамен' AND T1.Оценка <= 2;`

Причина браковки: По словам преподавателя данное решение является нелогичным, а именно `T3.Код_Студента = T1.Код_Студента` это условие делает запрос нелогичным. Но без него рандом начинает работать криво и преподаватели рандомятся по дисциплинам
[image: Неправильный рандом]

Если не убирать условие `T3.Код_Студента = T1.Код_Студента`, то рандом начинает работать правильно
[image: Правильный рандом]

Прошу вас помочь с решением и объяснением

Comment: мне вот интересно, вы сами придумали называть таблицы и столбцы русскими словами, или учат? это какой-то отдельный вид мазохизма постоянно переключать раскладку при написании запросов? или графическим интерфейсом исключительно пользуетесь?

Answer (score 1):

Подсказка: нужно собрать преподавателей по дисциплине, прицепив к каждому случайное значение, а потом отобрать одного с помощью MIN или MAX по этому случайному значению. А потом уже этого препода прицепить через Нагрузка к двойкам в Результаты_Сессии.

"T3.Код_Студента = T1.Код_Студента" нелогично потому, что T1 и T3 - это Результаты_Сессии.